# Display second layout for listview in position 5

Tags: android, listview

I want to display the second layout inside listview at position 5, all the other positions 1,2,3,4 will be the first layout.

My code is,

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
    //View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if(convertView == null) {
        if (type == 0) {
            // Inflate the layout with image
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_from_category_list, null);

            // Then we get reference for ImageLoader
            ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.getTag();
            ImageView img1;
            TextView tv2;
            if(img == null){
                img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                convertView.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
            }
            img1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            String name = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get("name");
            String location = (String) ((Map<?, ?>)getItem(position)).get("location");
            String url = (String) ((Map<?, ?>)getItem(position)).get("images");
            String url1 = (String) ((Map<?, ?>)getItem(position)).get("profile_pic");
            tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u>"+name+" @ "+location+"</u>"));

            // do ImageLoader
            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(1000)).build();
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage(url, img);
            imageLoader.displayImage(url1, img1, options);

            final String category_id = (String) ((Map<?, ?>)getItem(position)).get("category_id");
            final String event_id = (String) ((Map<?, ?>)getItem(position)).get("id");
            final String cat_id = (String) ((Map<?, ?>)getItem(position)).get("cat_id");

            img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, EventsMoreAsCategory.class);

                    if(cat_id.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        i.putExtra("category_id", cat_id);
                        i.putExtra("event_id", event_id);
                    }
                    else if(cat_id.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {

                    }
                    else {
                        i.putExtra("category_id", category_id);
                        i.putExtra("event_id", event_id);
                    }

                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, EventsMoreAsCategory.class);

                    if(cat_id.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        i.putExtra("category_id", cat_id);
                        i.putExtra("event_id", event_id);
                    }
                    else if(cat_id.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {

                    }
                    else {
                        i.putExtra("category_id", category_id);
                        i.putExtra("event_id", event_id);
                    }

                    context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            int i;
            for(i=0;i<position;i++)
            {
                if(i == 4)
                {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_ads, null);

                ImageView ads = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

                imageLoader.displayImage("@drawable//"+R.drawable.event_image, ads);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.events_ads, null);

            ImageView ads = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage("@drawable//"+R.drawable.event_image, ads);
        }

    }

    // return the view
    return convertView;
}
```

I have tried, but the second layout is not coming at position 5. Is there any solution. Now the output is, first and second layout as even and odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getViewTypeCount()` - Returns how many types of rows you have.

`getItemViewType(int position)` - Returns information on which layout type you should use based on its position

Using getItemViewType you can define the layout you need to use.

Like this

```
public static final int TYPE_1 = 1;
public static final int TYPE_2 = 2;

public int getItemTypeCount(){
     return 5;
}

public int getItemType(int position){
    // Your if else code and return type ( TYPE_1 to TYPE_5 )
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    // Return the right kind of view based on getItemType(position)

    int type = getItemType(position);
    if(type == TYPE_1){
        // create (or reuse) TYPE_1 view
    } else if() {
    }......

    return myView;

}
```

In your case,you have only 2 types of rows,so `getItemTypeCount()` should return 2.